# Extend bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig form theme

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to customize the form layout in a symfony 3 project, by extending bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig form theme.

```
{# app/Resources/views/app/custom_bootstrap_metronic.html.twig #}
{% use "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block checkbox_widget -%}
{%- set parent_label_class = 
parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) -%}
    {% if 'checkbox-inline' in parent_label_class %}
        {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
    {% else -%}
        <div class="checkbox">
            {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
        </div>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

and i added this in the configuration file:

```
{# app/config/config.yml #}
twig:
   # form_themes: [bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig]
   form_themes: [form/custom_bootstrap_metronic.html.twig]
```

what i want is to override the checkbox_widget so the rendered html will like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="mt-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="appbundle_accept" 
            name="appbundle[accept]" value="1"> 
            Label
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="appbundle_accept" 
            name="appbundle[accept]" value="1"> 
            Label
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't do that because the parent() function returns the checkbox_widget block from bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig and i need the checkbox_widget block from form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: My guess is you actually want to override the Bootstrap based checkbox. Are you going to use it on multiple occasions?

Comment: Yes, in every form in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did is i copied the code from "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" in a file called "custom_bootstrap_metronic.html.twig" then i customized it.

```
{% block checkbox_widget -%}
    {%- set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) -%}
    {% if 'checkbox-inline' in parent_label_class %}
        {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent(), label_attr: {class: 'mt-checkbox'}}) -}}
    {% else -%}
        <div class="mt-checkbox-inline">
            {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent(), label_attr: {class: 'mt-checkbox'}}) -}}
        </div>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block checkbox_radio_label %}
    {# Do not display the label if widget is not defined in order to prevent double label rendering #}
    {% if widget is defined %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if parent_label_class is defined %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' ' ~ parent_label_class)|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is not same as(false) and label is empty %}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{- widget|raw }} 
            {{ label is not same as(false) ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain)) -}}
            <span></span> {# added this line #}
        </label>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock checkbox_radio_label %}
```

Comment: upvote, works for me too, just copy needed twig templates  from your  vendor's Twig/Resources/views/Form/ or copy only  needed blocks bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig